# How do I fix Access violation writing exception

Tags: c, pointers, access-violation, first-chance-exception

I have following bit of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char *convertire(char *sir)
{
    char *sir2="";
    while (*sir)
    {
        *sir2 = toupper(*sir);
        sir++;
    }
    return (sir2);
}
void main(void)
{
    char *sir = "Home is good";
    char *sir2 = convertire(sir);
    printf("Sirul obtinut este : %s\n", sir2);
    _getch();
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following error

```
First-chance exception at 0x00E3141B in pointeri.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00E35858. If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Can you please help me resolve this ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, please write your questions as elaborative as possible.

Comment: When I try to built this code, the compiler show me this: First-chance exception at 0x00E3141B in pointeri.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00E35858.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued. So I can't to compile this code. What's the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You will also need to track the start of `sir2`, basically you would need to modify `convertire()` like this:

```
char *convertire(char *sir)
{   
    char *p;
    char *sir2=(char *)malloc(strlen(sir)+1);
    p = sir2;
    while (*sir)
      {   
        *sir2++ = toupper(*sir++);
      }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` in C.

Comment: In all fairness, while it is a good observation, it is not what the OP asked :P Maybe you made him miss an important lesson: that *making a program compile* does not automatically equal to having it do what he want.

Comment: @Jongware, well to me it looked like OP wanted to get "Home is good" converted to the upper case, something like "HOME IS GOOD", and this would happen with the convertire() posted above. So both the purposes are accomplished here, program compiles and provides desired result.

Comment: @CoolGuy You would be surprised to learn how often it is used.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *sir2="";
```

There is no enough memory allocated for your pointer `sir2` and is also just read-only.

You need something like

```
char *sir2 = malloc(strlen(sir1) + 1);
```

Accessing unallocated memory leads to undefined behavior and might cause crash. This can't be handled in any other way other than allocating memory for your pointer.

Comment: is it really _no memory_?

Comment: The program won't work as expected when this is done too. I believe that the OP wants to capitalize each letter of `sir` and store it in `sir2` and then, print `sir2`.

Comment: @Jongware Yes you are right. I corrected my wordings now